# extern "C" inside namespace

Tags: c++

Do you know why the code below fails to compile?

```
#include <iostream>

namespace C {
    extern "C" {
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h> // open()
#include <unistd.h> // read()
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int fd = C::open("./main.cpp", O_RDONLY);
    C::read(fd, 0, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

The error from the GCC 4.4 compiler is:

```
error: ‘read’ is not a member of ‘C’
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why not just include unistd.h?

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Why would it not link?

Comment: @Jerry: See 7.5.6: "At most one function with a particular name can have C language linkage. Two declarations for a function
with C language linkage with the same function name (ignoring the namespace names that qualify it) that
appear in different namespace scopes refer to the same function. Two declarations for an object with C language
linkage with the same name (ignoring the namespace names that qualify it) that appear in different
namespace scopes refer to the same object."

Comment: @BillyONeal: Yes, I've read it. I probably shouldn't have made the statement nearly so strongly. I tried this back when namespaces were a new thing, and at that time the names got mangled based on the namespace, regardless of the `extern "C"` linkage spec. Then again, I've never tried it again, and thinking about it for even a moment, chances are pretty good that compilers get this right nowadays.

Comment: @Jerry: I know I've seen this before... I'm trying to remember where. I think it was to allow #include ing windows.h and ntddk.h in the same program.... everything in Windows.h got put in Windows:: and everything in Ntddk got put in Ddk:: -- because there are conflicting defs of a few things in there. Can't remember the book I saw that in though. Oh well :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not inject everything into a namespace under a header. In this case, `read` is a macro and it is evaluated to something else before namespace resolution rules take effect.

Comment: But wait a moment. THere must be something different than that. Why if i remove #include <iostream> the program compiles and links with both C::open() and C::read() ?